# Doctrine - PHP Warning: include_once(): Failed opening Table for inclusion

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 1.2.
The code is trying to include some entities (in the example, AdvertiserUsers) by adding the suffix "Table" at the end.  I print a trace at the end of this message.

The thing is, my app does not use these files! I have my models called AdvertiserUsers on the style, with no need for an AdvertiserUsersTable file. Actually, I have my models called "AdvertiserUsers" only, and my app works OK without it (ugly warnings aside - which I want to get rid of).

I don't know why it tries to include these files that are not needed. This is the actual issue.

As a side note, my application has been doing this after I integrated an external module (from a freelance) that used a direct connection - no Doctrine - and happens on this module, when having to integrate both and using separate connections for different data.

Trace:

```
[26-Jul-2011 22:59:06] PHP Warning:  include_once(AdvertiserUsersTable.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
[26-Jul-2011 22:59:06] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'AdvertiserUsersTable.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/stats-from-zero/application/../library:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/stats-from-zero/library:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/stats-from-zero/library/doctrine::/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/stats-from-zero/library/recaptcha-php-1.10:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/stats-from-zero/public/php-form-builder-class:.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/stats-from-zero/application/modules/stats/models:/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/stats-from-zero/application/modules/stats/forms') in /usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
```

Answer (score 1):

`AdvertiserUsersTable.php` does not exist. Check name of that file & specific directory. It should be there

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I got into that already, what I'm saying is that my app does not need AdvertiserUsersTable and I don't have such a file. I have a DoctrineRecord called AdvertiserUsers, nothing else - the need for a XTable.php file is created somehow by Doctrine, not by my app - and I don't know why.